# winjs sqlite database is locked

Tags: sqlite, windows-runtime, winjs

I use in a Windows 8 project (js/html) the SQLite3-WinRT library https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT.
I create a function that is called in a for loop.
I have this error:

> SQLiteError: 0x800700aa: eachAsync("INSERT INTO home (id, url, cksum)VALUES (16, 'main_page_2.jpg', 'e0d046ca3421a3c2df328b293ad5981a');", ) database is locked

I think the error is because I create a new connection every iteration of loop, but I don't understand another method. Who can help me?

This is the function:

```
function insertInDB(dbPath, tbName, arrayCol, arrayVal) {
SQLite3JS.openAsync(dbPath).then(function (db) {
var query = "INSERT INTO " + tbName;
var column = " (";
var values = "VALUES (";
for (var i = 0; i < arrayCol.length; i++) {
if (i == arrayCol.length - 1) {
column = column + arrayCol[i] + ")";
} else {
column = column + arrayCol[i] + ", ";
}
}
for (var i = 0; i < arrayVal.length; i++) {
if (i == arrayCol.length - 1) {
values = values + arrayVal[i] + ");";
} else {
values = values + arrayVal[i] + ", ";
}
}
query = query + column + values;
return db.eachAsync(query).done(function () {
console.log("Ok");
db.close();
},
function (error) { console.log(error); },
function (progress) { });
});
}
```

and this is the loop that call a previous function:

```
listHome.forEach(function(value, index, array){
var valconfig = new Array(value.id, "'" + value.url + "'", "'" + value.cksum + "'");
console.log("id=" + value.id + " url=" + value.url + " ck=" + value.cksum);

                    insertInDB(sqlPath, "home", colconfig, valconfig);   
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, your calling code is iterating over a list of values synchronously.  `listHome.forEach` will call `insertInDB` for each item in `listHome` ... but it doesn't wait for `insertInDB` to return before making the next call to `insertInDB`.

Inside `insertInDB` you have call to `SQLite3JS.openAsync` and `db.eachAsync` - both asynchronous methods. After perusing SQLite3JS a little bit (which looks pretty cool), both of those methods return promises, where internally they call into a WinRT component. Great design.

So this is what I suspect is happening: one of the asynchronous calls in `insertInDB` puts a lock on the database. However, `insertInDB` returns control back to the `listHome.forEach` loop **as soon** as it hits the first asynchronous method call. If the lock on the database remains once `forEach` gets to the next item in listHome, then the operation will attempt to write to a locked database. Hence the error.

I'll think about this a little bit and see if I can come up with a solution.

-- edit --

Okay, I have a solution that might work for you. You might want to create a "DataBaseHelper" class that will queue up the transactions that you need to make in the database.

Here's a rough prototype that I threw together:

[Replaces your foreach loop]

```
DBHelper.queueUpdates(listHome);
```

[DBHelper module definition]

```
(function () {

    var _queue;

    function queueUpdates(array) {        
        _queue = array;
        scheduleUpdates();
    }

    function scheduleUpdates() {
        if (_queue.length > 0) {
            var transaction = _queue.pop();
            insertInDB("path", "table", "column", transaction);
        }
    }

    function insertInDB(dbPath, tbName, arrayCol, arrayVal) {
        return SQLite3JS.openAsync(dbPath).then(function (db) {

            // Construct your SQL query ...

            return db.eachAsync(query).done(function () {
                db.close();
                scheduleUpdates();
            },
            function (error) { console.log(error); },
            function (progress) { });
        });
    }

    WinJS.Namespace.define("DBHelper", {
        queueUpdates: queueUpdates
    })
})();
```

Comment: In your code snippet, no values are specified for "dbPath, "arrayCol" arguments in InsertInDB, so I couldn't assume anything there. I assume that your SQL query works. "transaction" represents the individual items from the listHome array. As far as iterating over the values in listHome, the code that I posted uses recursion to iterate over the values, checking to see if its reached the end of the array before scheduling another transaction.

Comment: I use your code but the query insert only last value of listhome.

Comment: i correct the error. Now i have another problem. if i called 2 times the function  DBHelper.queueUpdates i have the same error for example:

DBHelper.queueUpdates(sqlPath, "table1", colconfig, listHome);
DBHelper.queueUpdates(sqlPath, "table2", lconfig, listHome);

i have error database is locked